# How do I close/delete my YouTube account?

Tags: youtube, account-management

How do I close/delete my YouTube account?

I saw Google's help page [How do I close/delete my YouTube account?](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=55759&topic=16602&ctx=topic).  But, under Settings->Overview->Advanced, I have no option to close my account.

I closed my Google+ account a while ago, so I don't think that part of the help article applies to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first disconnect your account from your Google+ account. If it is linked, you don't have an option to close your Youtube account.

You can disconnect your Google+ account from your Youtube account by going to the main settings page. You would be able to see it next to your avatar. After doing so, you can close your account under “Advanced".

I do not have any ideas on how you close your account other than contact Youtube, if the above steps do not help you.

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't have a Google+ account.  I'll try contacting YouTube, but I don't have high hopes that will work.

Comment: So did contacting them work out?

Answer (score 1):

I did get a response from Google.  Here's what they told me:

> I know this can be confusing, so I hope this explanation will help clarify.
>   It appears that you do not actually have a full YouTube account. If you see your email address or Google+ name in the top right corner, it's just informing you that you're logged into your Google Account.
>
> Without a full YouTube account, you have no public presence on YouTube. In order to do things like leave comments, upload videos, and make playlists, you’ll need to create a YouTube channel. To create a channel, please visit this page: http://www.youtube.com/create_channel

So a Google account means you have a YouTube account (really, it's the same account -- so you can't delete just the YouTube part), but does not mean you have a YouTube *channel*.  Confusing because you can still "like" a video and do some other things without the channel.